# css grid, gap, centering

Tags: css, css-grid

Пытаюсь получить нижний блок такой же как верхний, но на гридах. Не пойму как центрировать с учетом отступов между кнопками в 50 пикселей. Подскажите, где ошибка. Песочница: https://jsfiddle.net/4gu52o0q/

```css
.block1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.block1__list {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block1__list:first-child .block1__btn:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.block1__list:nth-child(2) .block1__btn:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 40px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-areas: "title title title title title" ". btn1 btn2 btn3 ." ". btn4 . btn5 ." ". . btn6 . .";
}

.block__title {
  grid-area: title;
}

.block__btn:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: btn1;
}

.block__btn:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: btn2;
}

.block__btn:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: btn3;
}

.block__btn:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: btn4;
}

.block__btn:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: btn5;
}

.block__btn:nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: btn6;
}
```

```html
<section class="block1">
  <h1 class="block1__title">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
  <div class="block1-lists">
    <div class="block1__list">
      <button class="block1__btn">btn1</button>
      <button class="block1__btn">btn2</button>
      <button class="block1__btn">btn3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block1__list">
      <button class="block1__btn">btn4</button>
      <button class="block1__btn">btn5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block1__list">
      <button class="block1__btn">btn6</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="block">
  <h1 class="block__title">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
  <button class="block__btn">btn1</button>
  <button class="block__btn">btn2</button>
  <button class="block__btn">btn3</button>
  <button class="block__btn">btn4</button>
  <button class="block__btn">btn5</button>
  <button class="block__btn">btn6</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Делай 5 колонок.

Comment: @Qwertiy grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); это не 5 колонок?

Comment: Сорри, я просто код не читал. Не угадал, значит.